# How to connect 3 table but 2nd table is conjuction in Eloquent? and retrieve the data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how to connect 3 tables with 2 model? It will awkward to create media_genres model too. and retrieve the title, and genre too.

> In genres table have 1. Action, 2 Genre. in Medias table have 1 movie
> Resident Evil.

It should return 2 rows cause i assign 2 genre with that ID in media_genres table. In bottom the eloquent not relations to genre. it just return without genre.

medias table

```
Media_ID mediumIncrements // 1. Resident Evil
Title string 255
Synopsis text nullable
```

media_genres table

```
Media_ID unsignedMediumInteger (foreign of medias table)
Genre_ID unsignedSmallInteger (foreign of genres table)
```

genres table

```
Genre_ID smallIncrements // 1. Action, 2. Drama
Genrename string 100
```

Media model

```
protected $table = 'media';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = 'Media_ID';

public function genre()
{
    $this->hasOne(Media_Genre::class, 'Media_ID', 'Media_ID');
}
```

Genre model

```
protected $table = 'genre';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = 'Genre_ID';
```

Media_Genre model

```
protected $table = 'media_genres';
public $timestamps = false;
```

Controller

```
return Media::where('Media_ID', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To link media table with genres via a third pivot table, use the relation belongsToMany

```
public function genre()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class, 'media_genres', 'media_id', 'genre_id');
}
```

then in your controller use `with` to get the media and its genre.

```
return Media::with('genre')->where('Media_ID', 1)->get();
```

Comment: How to return the value of table only? in result it return other key like pivot?

Comment: @davidstephen Why would you bother remove them. They are part of the relation, that's why they are there. if you want to remove them, use response Object, use $hidden attribute in genre model or anything